# xpath search from importxml function in google sheets

Tags: xpath

how do I get "Div/yield" value from [here](https://www.google.com/finance?q=ibm&ei=Kg-aWNnlGsn_jAHphIqQBg)?  i've tried `//td[node()='Div/yield'` and `//td[text()='Div/yield'`.

and `//td[@data-snapfield='latest_dividend-dividend_yield']/following-sibling::td`

Comment: Looks like there's a newline at the end of that table cell, so maybe try: 

    `//td[normalize-space(.)='Div/yield']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@sideshowbarker is correct in that there's a newline at the end so looking for an element with the exact text would return 0 results. Another way to do this (one is through @sideshowbarker's answer) is to look for an element that contains this text. So the first step is:

`//td[contains(text(),'Div/yield')]`

But you don't need this. Your last answer is on the right track. You've identified the element that you're after, but I think you're looking for the text. So you need to add `text()` at the end:

`//td[@data-snapfield='latest_dividend-dividend_yield']/following-sibling::td/text()`

But if you want to use the field name, so you could use the xpath for the other fields as well, then just combine these:

`//td[contains(text(),'Field name')]/following-sibling::td/text()`

Now just replace Field name with the field you're after..

e.g. 'Div/yield': `//td[contains(text(),'Div/yield')]/following-sibling::td/text()`